# Python Cassandra floating precision loss

Tags: python, cassandra, floating-point, precision, cassandra-python-driver

I'm sending data back and forth Python and Cassandra. I'm using both builtin  `float` types in my python program and the data type for my Cassandra table. If I send a number `955.99` from python to Cassandra, in the database it shows `955.989999`. When I send a query in python to return the value I just sent, it is now `955.989990234375`.

I understand the issue with precision loss in python, I just wanted to know if there's any built-in mechanisms in Cassandra that could prevent this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python `float` is an 64-bit IEEE-754 **double** precision binary floating point number. Use [`double`](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html) in Cassandra for a matching type.

Comment: While that works for some of the values, some like `8.83` are turning into `null` despite it have the same types like the other values, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Ahh it wasn't the values themselves that were an issue. I used `DROP` to remove the float columns and used `ADD` to put them back. The columns that I didn't name into something else had the null values in them.

Comment: Keep in mind that floatingpoint values like float or double always have issues with precision.

Comment: Great point Mandraenke.  If precision is important, the cql decimal type should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you cannot change your column definition for some reason, converting your float value to string and passing str to the cassandra-driver will also solve your problem.

It will be able to generate the precise decimal values form str.